# VMware Workstation 8 shared folders not working with my client Fedora 17 install

Tags: network-share, fedora, vmware-workstation

I have a Windows7 box running a stripped down Fedora 17 (no gui) server running inside VMware 8 Workstation. When I proceed to install the vmware-tools, the shared folders feature fails to compile the vmhgfs module, although I have all the utilities installed, i.e. gcc, make, kernel-headers, binutils, etc. I have not found any information online that addresses this issue. I find all kinds of hacks to the vmware source to work around other versions of Fedora, but not for version 17 (Beefy Miracle). If I try and enabled shared folders and point it to a local folder, /mnt/hgfs has nothing in it. If anyone has experience fixing this, or an article, patch, etc, please let me know. Would love to get this feature working.

The following is the error I receive:

```
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/linux/driver.c: In function â__check_disable_hostâ:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:2498:1: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/linux/driver.c: In function â__check_disable_guestâ:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:2501:1: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/linux/driver.c: In function â__check_disable_msiâ:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:2504:1: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/linux/driver.c: In function â__check_disable_msixâ:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/linux/driver.c:2507:1: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by
  LD [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmci.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmci.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmci.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.4.3-1.fc17.x86_64'
make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
 Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only'
cp -f vmci.ko ./../vmci.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only'
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only'
make -C /lib/modules/3.4.3-1.fc17.x86_64/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.4.3-1.fc17.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/message.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/dir.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/rpcout.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/filesystem.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/cpName.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/request.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/link.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/module.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/hgfsUtil.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/stubs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/tcp.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/hgfsEscape.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/file.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/super.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/dentry.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/inode.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/bdhandler.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/vmci.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/transport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/fsutil.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/cpNameLinux.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/hgfsBd.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/backdoor.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/backdoorGcc64.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/cpNameLite.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/kernelStubsLinux.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/page.o
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/file.c:128:4: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/file.c:128:4: warning: (near initialization for âHgfsFileFileOperations.fsyncâ)
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/filesystem.c: In function âHgfsGetRootDentryâ:
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/filesystem.c:379:4: error: implicit declaration of function âd_alloc_rootâ [-Wer
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/filesystem.c:379:19: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a ca
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/filesystem.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:121:4: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled b
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:121:4: warning: (near initialization for âHgfsDirInodeOperations.createâ
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:124:4: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled b
/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:124:4: warning: (near initialization for âHgfsDirInodeOperations.mkdirâ)
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.4.3-1.fc17.x86_64'
make: *** [vmhgfs.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only'

The filesystem driver (vmhgfs module) is used only for the shared folder
feature. The rest of the software provided by VMware Tools is designed to work
independently of this feature.

If you wish to have the shared folders feature, you can install the driver by
running vmware-config-tools.pl again after making sure that gcc, binutils, make
and the kernel sources for your running kernel are installed on your machine.
These packages are available on your distribution's installation CD.
[ Press Enter key to continue ]
```

Comment: What version of Vmware Worstation are you specifically running? `8.0.1`, `8.0.2`?

Comment: VMware Workstation 8.0.4 for Windows

Comment: I found some documentation stating that the vmware tools source is incompatible with the linux 3.4.x kernel and you had to replace the instances of `d_alloc_root` with `d_make_root` in `filesystem.c` in `vmblock.tar` and recompile to make it work.

Still no go. 

Anyone able to help with this one?

Comment: can you ensure that you have the following packages installed? `kernel-devel kernel-headers gcc make`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. I booted up in the 3.3.4 kernel instead, and now everything works. I guess vmware-tools are not supporting 3.4 kernels yet.